# Why is my slack app posting only ephemeral messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slack

I have a rails app that is deployed to heroku. Its a poll app, ongoing development. The problem is all the message it sends via the response_url are tagged "Only visible to you" and isn't visible to the other users in my workspace. response_type isn't set to ephemeral either. I tried looking for the solution but couldn't find any.

Comment: While the question asked the opposite, the answer explains both options.